# react-dropzone: prevent inner element from showing file picker

Tags: reactjs, react-dropzone

I'm currently using the [react-dropzone](https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone/) plugin and encountered a use case that's not exactly described in the documentations.

Basically, I have the following elements:

- An outer dropzone that should allow both

  - Drag-and-drop, and
  - Native file picker `on click`
- An inner button that does not show the native file picker `on click`

The problem I'm having right now is to stop the native file picker from showing up when the *inner* button is clicked.

To illustrate my example, you can paste this code into the [View Code](https://react-dropzone.js.org/#section-event-propagation) section.

```js
import React from 'react';
import {useDropzone} from 'react-dropzone';

function Dropzone(props) {
  const {getRootProps, getInputProps, open, acceptedFiles} = useDropzone({
    // Disable click and keydown behavior
    noKeyboard: true
  });

  const files = acceptedFiles.map(file => (
    <li key={file.path}>
      {file.path} - {file.size} bytes
    </li>
  ));

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div {...getRootProps({className: 'dropzone'})}>
        <input {...getInputProps()} />
        <p>Drag 'n' drop some files here</p>
        <InnerButton />
      </div>
      <aside>
        <h4>Files</h4>
        <ul>{files}</ul>
      </aside>
    </div>
  );
}

function InnerButton(props) {
  const { getRootProps } = useDropzone({ noClick: true }); // doesn't stop the parent's input file picker

  return (
    <button
      {...getRootProps({
        onClick: (event) => event.stopPropagation(), // this is bad for many reasons
      })}
      type="button">
      This button should not open the file picker
    </button>
  );
}

<Dropzone />
```

I figured that using `event.stopPropagation()` is one way but I've read that it should be avoided for many reasons ([source 1](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing#stopping-bubbling), [source 2](https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone/issues/541#issuecomment-475170458)). I tried using `noClick: true` in the inner button but it doesn't work - most likely because  it can't stop the parent's `<input>` tag.

Is there another approach that I should try, other than using `stopPropagation`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got an answer [on GitHub](https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone/issues/1013#event-3970429221), posting it here in case anyone else encounters the same question.

> There's no way around it. You have to use `stopPropagation()` to stop the event from bubbling up the DOM. Your other option is to use `noClick` on the parent as well.
>
> `noClick` only disables opening the file selector when clicking on the dropzone node. It does not prevent the event from bubbling.
>
> The only thing we can do is to provide a `noClickBubbling` option that calls `stopPropagation()`, but the user can already do that.